# Passing a literal ? to sp_MSforeachdb

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to search for the `?` character in a string, but across all dbs on a server. Since the `?` mark is a placeholder for the database name, how may I format the query so it knows I mean to search for `?` and not replace it with the database name?

The WHERE clause at this time is:

```
WHERE DirectoryPath LIKE ''%?%''
```

This renders to:

```
WHERE DirectoryPath LIKE '%DATABASENAME%'
```

I need it to render as:

```
WHERE DirectoryPath LIKE '%?%'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Updates thanks to Martin.* If you view the text for the procedure:

```
EXEC sys.sp_helptext N'sp_MSforeachdb';
```

You will see that it passes the `@replacechar` as `NCHAR(1)` (default `N'?'`) into `sys.sp_MSforeach_worker`. Peeling back another layer of the onion, you will see really ugly code in that procedure that loops through every character in the command and rebuilds it. I didn't study every single line but I could not find any evidence of an ability to escape or preserve the actual question mark conditionally, unless - as Martin points out - you override it with a *different* character that can't naturally appear in the command. So perhaps something like:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT ''Ƥ'', other_columns FROM [?].dbo.whatever
  WHERE DirectoryPath LIKE ''%?%'';', N'Ƥ';

-- Ƥ is NCHAR(420), chosen randomly
```

Since it is really looking for the literal `?` character, a possibly easier way would be this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'PRINT ''?'' + ''-'' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0x3F)';
```

So extrapolating that, we can construct this ugly variation:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT ''?'', other_columns FROM [?].dbo.whatever
  WHERE DirectoryPath LIKE ''%'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), 0x3F) + ''%'';';
```

That all said, you could write your own version of `sp_MSforeachdb` that uses a *different* default value for `@replacechar`, so you don't have to override it manually. You probably should be writing your own version instead of relying on the built-in procedure anyway, as I point out in these posts - it is unsupported, undocumented, and actually has a very high frequency bug where it skips databases due to the cursor options used:

- https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb
- https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: Thank you so much for that. That is working. I would definitely like to have my own version of the sp_MSforeachdb at some point but this gets what I need done in a clever way. Thank you.

Comment: `@replacechar` is passed into `sp_MSforeachdb` as well as the second parameter so `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'SELECT ''?!?''', N'!'` works fine.

Comment: Ah, thanks @MartinSmith, I looked right past that. So in theory you could just change the `?` where you *want* the database name replaced to `!` or some other character, and then it will leave your literal `?` characters alone. Two challenges remain: (a) it's `NCHAR(1)`, so you have to choose a single character that has no chance of being in the rest of the command naturally, and (b) you still have the potential issue of `sp_MSforeachdb` skipping databases.